# reshape df for time series in R

Tags: r

Hopefully you guys can help me. I'm relative new to programming and this task goes beyond my skills. Background: intern by a company and they have a dataset like this. I want to see how accurate I can predict Traffic jams and how many minutes I can predict (so T-1 is pretty obvious, but T-10, so 10 minutes in advance would be more exciting how accurate it will be).

I have a dataframe that looks like this (fictive input):
Time = HMS, location = location on a highway, rain = rainfall, Traffic Jam = binair (1=yes, 2=no).

```
Time     | day | speed | location | Rain | Traffic jam |

00:01:00 | Thurs| 102.1| 56.3 | 12.2| 0

00:02:00 | Thurs| 102.1| 56.3 | 0    | 0

00:03:00 | Thurs| 102.1| 56.3 | 1.2| 0

00:04:00 | Thurs| 23.1| 56.3 | 12| 1

00:05:00 | Thurs| 102.1| 56.3 | 12.2| 0

07:00:00 | Thurs| 12.1| 56.3 | 32.2| 1
```

I want it to look like this:
where T-10 = time - 10 minutes and the values under time is the speed.

```
Location | Rain | Day | t-10 | t-8| t-..| t-1| Traffic Jam|

56.3| 12| Thurs| 90.2 | 88.3| ..| 90| 0| 

56.3| 12| Thurs| 90.2 | 88.3| ..| 90.4| 0| 

56.3| 12| Thurs| 90.2 | 58.3| ..| 24.3| 1|
```

So my question is how I can reshape my dataframe. I already googled an tried with aggregate, melt and cast, but it didn't worked..

Hopefully you guys can help me out and an explainable code would be awesome!

Kind regards, 
Arnand

Comment: I think there's no need at all to reshape your dataframe. I'd probably arrange the timestamp so it's on hourly time span. This way you can try to fit some regression model. You could also aggregate those individuals who are at the same hour and forecast with some Arima model. Just some ideas for you..

Comment: Thank for advice! I want o keep the minutes for an more accurate prediction (hour predictions in traffic jams aren't very accurate). But I will take a closer look into Arima! But still curious how to change a DF like how I want to, so I can learn how to do that